# An error occurred when executing task 'Build'

Tags: msbuild, identityserver4

#### Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem

Running build.ps1 file inside IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4/

This build issue was generated while building `IdentityServer4` project independently. i.e. IdentityServer4 project is isolated from other project.

#### Relevant parts of the log file

```
Using global .NET SDK

----------------------------------------
Setup
----------------------------------------
branch            : master
pre-release label :
version           : 0.1.0.0
version suffix    :
informational     : 0.1.0+1.Branch.master.Sha.e333ebb1284752e0e62ed4e9637961dce3aac501

========================================
Clean
========================================

========================================
Build
========================================
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj...
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency IdentityModel does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency IdentityServer4.Storage does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency System.Security.Cryptography.Cng does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103: Unable to find a stable package Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub with version
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103:   - Found 7 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 1.0.0-beta-62905-03 ]
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103:   - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'IdentityModel 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  Generating MSBuild file D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\obj\IdentityServer4.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\obj\IdentityServer4.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore failed in 946.03 ms for D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj.

Build FAILED.

D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency IdentityModel does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency IdentityServer4.Storage does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Logging does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1604: Project dependency System.Security.Cryptography.Cng does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'IdentityModel 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103: Unable to find a stable package Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub with version
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103:   - Found 7 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 1.0.0-beta-62905-03 ]
D:\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4.csproj : error NU1103:   - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
    15 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.48
An error occurred when executing task 'Build'.
Error: One or more errors occurred. (.NET Core CLI: Process returned an error (exit code 1).)
        .NET Core CLI: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

How can is solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing this package reference in IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4.csproj:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" PrivateAssets="All" />
```